# $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I can't seem to find a way to solve $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}\right)$$ 
 Is there really any way to solve it, or does it just not exist?

Answer (score 4):

This limit does not exist.
You can simply take the particular subsequence:
\begin{equation}
x_n = \frac{1}{(2\pi n)^3}
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}
x_n = \frac{1}{(\pi n)^3},  n\ \text{odd}
\end{equation}
so that they do not converge to the same value.